# Fastest array initialisation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, c++03

What is the fastest way to initialise, lets say, an integer array to a given value?

If I have char array, I can use memset:

```
char a[N];
memset( a, value, N );
```

I can't do memset if the array type != char and value != 0 or -1:

```
int a[N];
memset( a, value, N*sizeof(int) ); // INCORRECT!
```

So I wonder whether there is a way to do similar memory initialization for other array types.

Comment: `int x[] = {1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: Fastest way? Have a data block in your code (with a jump statement just before it) in inline assembly and point your array to it. But seriously, keep things standard: use `std::fill`

Comment: Fastest as in "fastest thing for me to type" or "fastest in speed"? If the latter, is array initialization speed *really* a bottleneck in your code? If so (and I find this unlikely) you should just rearchitect your code.

Comment: Nik Bougalis, actually both:). No the init is not a bottleneck, but it nice to save time with many small things.

Comment: Note: `std::fill` is about copying the same value all over the array (like `memset`), however there is also `std::generate` which allows you to produce a different value for each index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
char a[N];
std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), value);
```

Note that `std::begin` and `std::end` are defined as of C++11.

If you're using C++03, then this would work:

```
char a[N];
std::fill(a, a + N, value);
```

Comment: even with #include <iterator>

Comment: You can easily backport `begin` and `end` (among other iterator utilities) to C++03 in case you're in need of them.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be any way faster than aggregate initialization:

```
int x = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

If you want to initialize everything to zero, then you can leverage the syntax to value-initialize the entire array:

```
int x [50] = {};
```

This is different than:

```
int x[50];
```

Because when you specify an initializer, the uninitialized elements are value-initialized.  If you don't specify an initializer, then the elements are uninitialized.

Just because there cannot be a faster method than `int x[] = {....}`, it's not necessarily true that other methods are slower.  You need to profile in release mode on your actual platform to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use memset with any primitive types.

```
int a[N] 
memset(a, '0x00', N * sizeof (int))
```

Comment: That's likely (but not guaranteed) to work if the value is zero, but won't work for other values.

Answer (score 0):

You can memset any kind of object/primitive. Everything is stored in memory after all.

That said you do have to understand how your compiler and processor store the thing you're memset'ing to predict what you will get. It's very non portable and dangerous if done wrong.

A lot of performance on modern desktop processors depends on if the objects you are referencing are in cache or not. So it's difficult to say if it will be faster. It's likely to be faster all other things being equal.